# How to get LinkSys EA6400 setup working with error

Tags: wireless-networking, router

When I connect from my computer to my Linksys EA6400 and try to go to the Setup console linksyssmartwifi.com:52000 the spinner in the page never stops loading. Chrome Developer Console gives an error message reviewModelNumber is not defined.

It seems like this particular unit has a faulty version of the web console.

Is there a way to update the software of the router without having access to the web console or another way to configure this model?

Comment: Try connecting to the actual ip address of the router. There are way update the firmware, requires a special cables, if this is a new router get a replacement its only worth going to the effort if its not under warranty.  The firmware likely is corrupt and if thats the case, unless it has a back firmware, its likely bricked.

Comment: `When my Linksys EA6400 first connects to the network` - by `network` you mean another router?

Comment: @happy_soil I have changed the wording to hopefully be more clear (and correct!).

Comment: @Ramhound Connecting to the IP address gives the same behavior. It's probably bricked.